# The dist folder created by ui5-tooling build doesn't work when deployed to SCP

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I've been trying to use ui5-tooling to build my apps using VSCODE.
I'm able to develop and use ui5-tooling without any problems.

The issue arises when I try to build. It seems the `dist` folder is not valid if I try to deploy to SCP.

Here's what I do:

- After terminating my dev, I run `ui5 build` and the `dist` folder is created. No errors are shown.
- I then zip the contents of that zip folder and manually upload it into SCP.
- When I try to launch the app from within SCP, it can't find the `sap-ui-core.js` file, thus the app won't start

Interestingly, if I run a build the "old" way, i.e. using `Grunt.js`,  the `dist` folder created by Grunt seems to have all the stuff that I need. Zipping the dist folder created by the Grunt taks, and then deploying it to SCP works like a charm.

Is it possible to deploy the bundle dist folder created by `ui5 build` to SCP? How?

By the way... I'm trying this with a very simple demo skeleton template app.
So it is just a basic XML view with a title and nothing else. No dependencies, nor destinations nor nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
All I had to do was 2 things

- move the neo-app.json inside the webapp folder
- change the property "welcomeFile" to "/index.html"

Voila.